# Правила для ЧПУ

Tags: битрикс, чпу

**Задача** Раздел акций – настроить чпу адрес у постраничной навигации, сейчас при переходе на 2 страницу – у нее такой адрес: http://test.ru/actions/?PAGEN_1=2 А должно быть http://test.ru/actions/page2 
**Мое решение**
Я настраиваю инфоблок. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Далее, я использую правила 
Код

```html
Код
   array(
      "CONDITION"   =>   "#^/actions/page([0-9]+)/#",
      "RULE"   =>  'PAGEN_1=\$1', 
      "ID"   =>   "bitrix:news",
      "PATH"   =>   "/actions/index.php",
   ),
      array(
      "CONDITION" => "#^/actions/$",
      "RULE" => "",
      "ID" => "bitrix:news",
      "PATH" => "/actions/index.php",
   ),
```

но не срабатывает, почему не знаю. подскажите, пожалуйста. Что нужно сделать?
И еще ,не удается скопировать этот же шаблон компонента()

```html
<?
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/bitrix/header.php");
$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("TITLE", "Акции");
$APPLICATION->SetTitle("Акции");
\Bags\DivTextContent::setVisible(false);
?>
<?
$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
        "bitrix:news", "actions", array(
    "DISPLAY_DATE" => "Y",
    "DISPLAY_PICTURE" => "Y",
    "DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT" => "Y",
    "SEF_MODE" => "Y",
    "AJAX_MODE" => "N",
    "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "content",
    "IBLOCK_ID" => "4",
    "NEWS_COUNT" => "1",
    "USE_SEARCH" => "N",
    "USE_RSS" => "N",
    "USE_RATING" => "N",
    "USE_CATEGORIES" => "N",
    "USE_REVIEW" => "Y",
    "USE_FILTER" => "N",
    "SORT_BY1" => "ACTIVE_FROM",
    "SORT_ORDER1" => "DESC",
    "SORT_BY2" => "SORT",
    "SORT_ORDER2" => "ASC",
    "CHECK_DATES" => "N",
    "PREVIEW_TRUNCATE_LEN" => "",
    "LIST_ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "d.m.Y",
    "LIST_FIELD_CODE" => array(
        0 => "DETAIL_TEXT",
        1 => "DETAIL_PICTURE",
        2 => "DATE_ACTIVE_FROM",
        3 => "DATE_ACTIVE_TO",
    ),
    "LIST_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
        0 => "",
        1 => "",
    ),
    "HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL" => "Y",
    "DISPLAY_NAME" => "Y",
    "META_KEYWORDS" => "-",
    "META_DESCRIPTION" => "-",
    "BROWSER_TITLE" => "-",
    "DETAIL_ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "d.m.Y",
    "DETAIL_FIELD_CODE" => array(
        0 => "DETAIL_TEXT",
        1 => "DETAIL_PICTURE",
        2 => "DATE_ACTIVE_FROM",
        3 => "DATE_ACTIVE_TO",
    ),
    "DETAIL_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
        0 => "",
        1 => "PHOTO",
        2 => "",
    ),
    "DETAIL_DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
    "DETAIL_DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "N",
    "DETAIL_PAGER_TITLE" => "Страница",
    "DETAIL_PAGER_TEMPLATE" => "",
    "DETAIL_PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "N",
    "SET_TITLE" => "N",
    "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "Y",
    "ADD_ELEMENT_CHAIN" => "Y",
    "SET_STATUS_404" => "Y",
    "INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN" => "N",
    "USE_PERMISSIONS" => "N",
    "GROUP_PERMISSIONS" => array(
        0 => "2",
    ),
    "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
    "CACHE_TIME" => "3600",
    "CACHE_FILTER" => "N",
    "CACHE_GROUPS" => "N",
    "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
    "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "Y",
    "PAGER_TITLE" => "Новости",
    "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => "Y",
    "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => "",
    "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => "N",
    "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => "36000",
    "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "N",
    "FILTER_NAME" => "",
    "FILTER_FIELD_CODE" => "",
    "FILTER_PROPERTY_CODE" => "",
    "NUM_NEWS" => "20",
    "NUM_DAYS" => "30",
    "YANDEX" => "Y",
    "MAX_VOTE" => "5",
    "VOTE_NAMES" => array(
        0 => "0",
        1 => "1",
        2 => "2",
        3 => "3",
        4 => "4",
    ),
    "CATEGORY_IBLOCK" => "",
    "CATEGORY_CODE" => "CATEGORY",
    "CATEGORY_ITEMS_COUNT" => "5",
    "MESSAGES_PER_PAGE" => "10",
    "USE_CAPTCHA" => "Y",
    "REVIEW_AJAX_POST" => "Y",
    "PATH_TO_SMILE" => "/bitrix/images/forum/smile/",
    "FORUM_ID" => "1",
    "URL_TEMPLATES_READ" => "",
    "SHOW_LINK_TO_FORUM" => "Y",
    "POST_FIRST_MESSAGE" => "Y",
    "SEF_FOLDER" => "/actions/",
    "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
    "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "N",
    "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",
    "AJAX_OPTION_ADDITIONAL" => "",
 "IS_SEF"=>"Y",
    "SEF_URL_TEMPLATES" => array(
        "news" => "",
        "section" => "",
        "detail" => "#ELEMENT_CODE#/",
    )
        ), false
);
?>

<? require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/bitrix/footer.php"); ?>
```

-через визуальный редактор, может, причина в поломке битрикса?

Comment: А значения GET параметров выводили?

Comment: @Mihanik. Да. по памяти скажу, так не решила. Там выводилось PAGEN_1=2. В чем причина?

Comment: возможно кому то пригодится. Разработал модуль "ЧПУ постраничной навигации", как раз решает эту проблему, спасибо! Ссылка на модуль: https://gorokhov.su/modules/pagen/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Работают правила:

```
array(
    "CONDITION"   =>   "#^/actions/page([0-9]+)#",
    "RULE"   =>  'PAGEN_1=$1',
    "ID"   =>   "bitrix:news",
    "PATH"   =>   "/actions/",
),
```

тогда адрес для 2 страницы будет /actions/page2

```
array(
    "CONDITION"   =>   "#^/actions/page([0-9]+).php#",
    "RULE"   =>  'PAGEN_1=$1',
    "ID"   =>   "bitrix:news",
    "PATH"   =>   "/actions/",
),
```

тогда адрес для 2 страницы будет /actions/page2.php

А если ставить слеш в конце, то битрикс применяет стандартные правила комплексного компонента news и пытается найти элемент.
Если всё же нужен слеш можно в .htaccess правила написать.
Не забудьте поменять шаблон пагинации. И не забывайте что если несколько компонентов будет на странице, то PAGEN_1 будет относиться к первому компоненту с пагинацией.

Comment: Спасибо огромнейшее, я уже не проверю. То есть, раз мой случай похож на первый, значит надо было написать в случае слеша` "CONDITION"=>"#^/actions/page([0-9]+)#/#"`. Так?

Comment: Нет, я попробовал все варианты и со слешем никак не получается. Это из-за реализации правил битрикса. Могу написать для htaccess правило, а для какой цели вообще это было? Поисковики вроде же нормально пагинацию обрабатывают.

Comment: Так  хотел заказчик. Я не сделала. в `htaccess` нужно было сделать `RewriteRule`?

Comment: Должно было быть как то так:
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /actions/page$

RewriteRule ^(.*) /actions/?PAGEN_1=$0 [QSA]`

Comment: спс.. огромное-)